# jquery modernizr margin 0 auto not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, modernizr

I have built a website which is displaying fine, until I include modernizr.min.js.

My body wrapper which is positioned 0 auto floats left with a margin at the top of around 50px, and out of curiosity i told it to float right, only to have it drift further left.

Has anybody had this problem before? If so did you fix it?

Many Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: what browser(s) are you testing with? Does adding modernizr cause a problem in all of them or just the one?

Answer (score 0):

Modernizr is best placed in your `<head>` **before any other script or CSS**. Maybe this could solve you problem.